# How to access control.unit.sock with Nginx for securely proxying Unit API

Tags: nginx, proxy, nginx-config

I'm trying to use Nginx as proxy to access control.unit.sock (Nginx Unit) as it is recommended here : [Securely Proyxing Unit Api](https://unit.nginx.org/howto/integration/). But Nginx is not able to access the socket.

I use the default configuration for Unit. unix:control.unit.sock is created as *root* with 600 permissions. Nginx uses the user : *www-data* by default.

How can I give Nginx access to this socket *securely* ? By avoid opening sockets on public interfaces in production or something else.
(For sure, Nginx has access if I set permission as 777.)

```
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/run/control.unit.sock;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider to run Unit with `--control` option and specify address that you want use (e.g. `--control 127.0.0.1:8080`).

Documentation https://unit.nginx.org/installation/#installation-startup:

> --control socket
>   Address of the control API socket. IPv4, IPv6, and Unix domain sockets
>   are supported.